# Is there a event listener for when the Electron startDrag ends?

Tags: macos, electron, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a file *drag and drop app* with *Electron* and I need to know if the file being dragged has been successfully dragged onto the user's desktop or if the drag and drop has been cancelled.

I tried using the `GlobalEventHandlers.ondragend` event listener, but it seems to be cancelled by `e.preventDefault()` needed for the `startDrag` function :

```
const dropAreaRef = document.body;
dropAreaRef.addEventListener("dragstart", handleExport, false);
dropAreaRef.addEventListener("dragend", handleExportEnd, false);

function handleExport(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.electron.startDrag(files);
}
function handleExportEnd(e) {
  console.log("export ended")
}
```

I have looked into the `Electron.WebContents` documentation, but cannot find any mention of a `startDrag` callback function or any electron `Instance Events`.